# Segmentation Fault C++, Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am going through and comparing a bunch of DNA sequences to find if it is a subset of another. I remove those that are subsets of another.

I'm using a linked list and I keep getting a segmentation fault somewhere around the output of the data back to the output file.

I'd also greatly appreciate feedback on overall code structure. I know its rather messy so I figured someone could point out some things that should be improved on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * Step 1. Load all sequences and their metadata into structures.
 *
 * Step 2. Start n^2 operation to compare sequences.
 * 
 * Step 3. Output file back to a different fasta file.
 */

typedef struct sequence_structure sequence_structure;

struct sequence_structure
{
  char *sequence;
  char *id;
  char *header;

  sequence_structure *next_sequence_structure;
  sequence_structure *previous_sequence_structure;

  int length;  
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *input_file;
  ofstream output_file;
  /* this is the TAIL of the linked list. This is a reversed linked list. */
  sequence_structure *sequences;


  int first_sequence               = 0;
  char *line                       = (char*) malloc( sizeof( char ) * 1024 ); 


  if( argc != 3 )
    {
      printf("This program requires a input file and output file as its argument!\n");
      return 0;
    }
  else
    {
      /* let's read the input file. */
      input_file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    }


  while( !feof(input_file) )
    {

      string string_line;

      fgets( line, 2048, input_file );
      string_line = line;

      if( string_line.length() <= 2 )
    break;

      if( string_line.at( 0 ) == '>' )
    {
      sequence_structure *new_sequence = (sequence_structure *) malloc( sizeof( sequence_structure ) );

      new_sequence->id = (char *) malloc( sizeof( char ) * ( 14 + 1 ) );
      string_line.copy( new_sequence->id, 14, 1 );
      (new_sequence->id)[14] = '\0';

      stringstream ss ( string_line.substr( 23, 4 ) );
      ss >> new_sequence->length;

      new_sequence->header = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) * ( string_line.length() + 1 ) );
      string_line.copy( new_sequence->header, string_line.length(), 0 );

      (new_sequence->header)[string_line.length()] = '\0';

      fgets( line, 2048, input_file );
      string_line = line;

      new_sequence->sequence = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) * ( string_line.length() + 1 ) );
      string_line.copy( new_sequence->sequence, string_line.length(), 0 );

      (new_sequence->sequence)[string_line.length()] = '\0';

      if( first_sequence == 0 )
        {
          sequences = new_sequence;
          sequences->previous_sequence_structure = NULL;

          first_sequence = 1;
        }
      else
        {
          sequences->next_sequence_structure = new_sequence;
          new_sequence->previous_sequence_structure = sequences;

          sequences = new_sequence;
        }

    }
      else
    {
      cout << "Error: input file reading error." << endl;
    }

    }

  fclose( input_file );
  free( line );

  sequence_structure *outer_sequence_node = sequences;
  while( outer_sequence_node != NULL )
    {

      sequence_structure *inner_sequence_node = sequences;
      string outer_sequence ( outer_sequence_node->sequence );

      while( inner_sequence_node != NULL )
    {
      string inner_sequence ( inner_sequence_node->sequence );
      if( outer_sequence_node->length > inner_sequence_node->length )
        {
          if( outer_sequence.find( inner_sequence ) != std::string::npos )
        {
          cout << "Deleting the sequence with id: " << inner_sequence_node->id << endl;
          cout << inner_sequence_node->sequence << endl;
          cout << "Found within the sequence with id: " << outer_sequence_node->id << endl;
          cout << outer_sequence_node->sequence << endl;

          sequence_structure *previous_sequence = inner_sequence_node->previous_sequence_structure;
          sequence_structure *next_sequence     = inner_sequence_node->next_sequence_structure;

          free( inner_sequence_node->id );
          free( inner_sequence_node->sequence );
          free( inner_sequence_node->header );

          if( next_sequence != NULL )
            next_sequence->previous_sequence_structure = previous_sequence;
          if( previous_sequence != NULL )
            {
              inner_sequence_node = previous_sequence;
              free( previous_sequence->next_sequence_structure );
              previous_sequence->next_sequence_structure = next_sequence;
            }

        }
        }

      inner_sequence_node = inner_sequence_node->previous_sequence_structure;
    }

      outer_sequence_node = outer_sequence_node->previous_sequence_structure;
      }

  output_file.open( argv[2], ios::out );

  while( sequences->previous_sequence_structure != NULL )
    {
        sequences = sequences->previous_sequence_structure;
    }


  sequence_structure *current_sequence = sequences;
  while( current_sequence->next_sequence_structure != NULL )
    {
      output_file << current_sequence->header;
      output_file << current_sequence->sequence;
      current_sequence = current_sequence->next_sequence_structure;
    }

  output_file << current_sequence->header;
  output_file << current_sequence->sequence;

  output_file.close();

  while( sequences != NULL )
    {
      cout << "Freeing sequence with this id: " << sequences->id << endl;
      free( sequences->id );
      free( sequences->header );
      free( sequences->sequence );
      if( sequences->next_sequence_structure != NULL )
    {
      sequences = sequences->next_sequence_structure;
      free( sequences->previous_sequence_structure );
    }
      else
    {
      sequences = NULL;
    }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest setting a break point at the start of your main and stepping through to see where you are getting the problem...

Comment: as I said its within the output to the output file ( towards the bottom ).

Comment: Could you supply us with an input file that causes the error?

Comment: looks like this: http://pastebin.com/L5CmdsPS. The actual input file is rather huge I just copied a sample.

Comment: Why write C code to use a minimal set of C++?  There's any number of places in your code where you're using hard-coded buffers that could be overrun. And, I see either use of unsafe C functions, or a lack of checking for success. Clean up the code (check return codes for starters), then come back with the question.

Comment: Which buffers are hardcoded? Besides ID, and the Input File Buffers?

Comment: Try running it with the gdb and when it segfaults type the command "backtrace" which should give you the location of the error. also in order for gdb to work you need to add '-g' to the g++ command to compile (i'm assuming your using g++ because windows doesnt segfault....)